# Android: How to get XML values inside a parent tag

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, sax

I wonder how can I retrieve the values inside the Phonebook tags here in my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<SyncDataResponse>
    <Videos>
        <PhonebookVideo>
            <firstname>V Michael</firstname> 
            <lastname>V De Leon</lastname> 
            <Address>V 5, Cat Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://cloud.somedomain.com/jm/26.flv</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookVideo>
        <PhonebookVideo>
            <firstname>V John</firstname> 
            <lastname>V Smith</lastname> 
            <Address>V 6, Dog Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://cloud.somedomain.com/jm/27.flv</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookVideo>
    </Videos>
    <Phonebook>
        <PhonebookEntry>
            <firstname>Michael</firstname> 
            <lastname>De Leon</lastname> 
            <Address>5, Cat Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://www.technobuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/Android-Emulator.jpg</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookEntry>
        <PhonebookEntry>
            <firstname>John</firstname> 
            <lastname>Smith</lastname> 
            <Address>6, Dog Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://www.cellphonehits.net/uploads/2008/10/android_openmoko.jpg</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookEntry>
        <PhonebookEntry>
            <firstname>Jember</firstname> 
            <lastname>Dowry</lastname> 
            <Address>7, Monkey Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://www.techdigest.tv/android.jpg</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookEntry>
        <PhonebookEntry>
            <firstname>Manilyn</firstname> 
            <lastname>Bulambao</lastname> 
            <Address>8, Tiger Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://www.ctctlabs.com/staticContent/weblog/xml-android.png</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookEntry>
    </Phonebook>
    <Audios>
        <PhonebookAudio>
            <firstname>A Michael</firstname> 
            <lastname>A De Leon</lastname> 
            <Address>A 5, Cat Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://cloud.somedomain.com/jm/a1.mp3</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookAudio>
        <PhonebookAudio> 
            <firstname>A John</firstname> 
            <lastname>A Smith</lastname> 
            <Address>A 6, Dog Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://cloud.somedomain.com/jm/a2.mp3</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookAudio>
        <PhonebookAudio> 
            <firstname>A Jember</firstname> 
            <lastname>A Dowry</lastname> 
            <Address>A 7, Monkey Street</Address> 
            <FileURL>http://cloud.somedomain.com/jm/a3.mp3</FileURL> 
        </PhonebookAudio>
    </Audios>
</SyncDataResponse>
```

**My code:**

On my main activity (ParsingXML.java), I have something like this:

```
/* Create a new TextView to display the parsingresult later. */
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("This is the parsing program...");


try {
  /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
  URL url = new URL("http://cloud.somedomain.com/jm/sampleXML.xml");
  url.openConnection();
  /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
  SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

  /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
  XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
  /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
  ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
  xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

  /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
  xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
  /* Parsing has finished. */

  /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
  List<ParsedExampleDataSet> parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

  /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */
  //tv.setText(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());

  String currentFile = null;
  String currentFileURL = null;
  Iterator i;
  i = parsedExampleDataSet.iterator();
  ParsedExampleDataSet dataItem;
  while(i.hasNext()){

       dataItem = (ParsedExampleDataSet) i.next();
       tv.append("\n" + dataItem.getfirstname());
       tv.append("\n" + dataItem.getlastname());
       tv.append("\n" + dataItem.getAddress());
       tv.append("\n" + dataItem.getFileURL());

       if(dataItem.getparenttag() == "Video"){
            currentFile = dataItem.getfirstname() + ".flv";
       }else if(dataItem.getparenttag() == "PhoneBook"){
            currentFile = dataItem.getfirstname() + ".jpg";
       }else if(dataItem.getparenttag() == "Audio"){
           currentFile = dataItem.getfirstname() + ".mp3";
       }

       currentFileURL = dataItem.getFileURL();
       startDownload(currentFile, currentFileURL);
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
  tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());

}
/* Display the TextView. */
this.setContentView(tv);
```

I have this on my handler (ExampleHandler.java):

```
 private StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

 private ParsedExampleDataSet mParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
 private List<ParsedExampleDataSet> mParsedDataSetList = new ArrayList<ParsedExampleDataSet>();

 // ===========================================================
 // Getter & Setter
 // ===========================================================

 public List<ParsedExampleDataSet> getParsedData() {
      return this.mParsedDataSetList;
 }

 // ===========================================================
 // Methods
 // ===========================================================

 /** Gets be called on opening tags like:
  * <tag>
  * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
  * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
 @Override
 public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
        this.mParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }

 }

 /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
  * </tag> */
 @Override
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
           throws SAXException {


      if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
           this.mParsedDataSetList.add(mParsedExampleDataSet);
           mParsedExampleDataSet.setparenttag("PhoneBook");
      }else if (localName.equals("firstname")) {
           mParsedExampleDataSet.setfirstname(mStringBuilder.toString().trim());
      }else if (localName.equals("lastname"))  {
          mParsedExampleDataSet.setlastname(mStringBuilder.toString().trim());
      }else if(localName.equals("Address"))  {
          mParsedExampleDataSet.setAddress(mStringBuilder.toString().trim());
      }else if(localName.equals("FileURL")){
          mParsedExampleDataSet.setFileURL(mStringBuilder.toString().trim());
      }

      mStringBuilder.setLength(0);
 }

 /** Gets be called on the following structure:
  * <tag>characters</tag> */
 @Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
      mStringBuilder.append(ch, start, length);
}
```

And I have this for the dataSet (ParsedExampleDataSet.java)

```
    private String parenttag = null;
    private String firstname = null;
    private String lastname=null;
    private String Address=null;
    private String FileURL=null;

    //Parent tag
    public String getparenttag() {
         return parenttag;
    }
    public void setparenttag(String parenttag) {
         this.parenttag = parenttag;
    }

    //Firstname
    public String getfirstname() {
         return firstname;
    }
    public void setfirstname(String firstname) {
         this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    //Lastname
    public String getlastname(){
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setlastname(String lastname){
        this.lastname=lastname;
    }

    //Address
    public String getAddress(){
        return Address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String Address){
        this.Address=Address;
    }

    //FileURL
    public String getFileURL(){
        return FileURL;
    }
    public void setFileURL(String FileURL){
        this.FileURL=FileURL;
    }
```

The output of this code is, since  has 4 records inside, it is expected to return 4 records. 
And yes, it returned 4 records but it just retrieves the first three records correctly
and then the fourth record is incorrect, the fourth record is actually the record in the PhonebookAudio tag.

It is exactly like this:

```
This is the parsing program...

Michael
De Leon
5, Cat Street
http://www.technobuzz.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/Android-Emulator.jpg

John
Smith
6, Dog Street
http://www.cellphonehits.net/uploads/2008/10/android_openmoko.jpg

Jember
Dowry
7, Monkey Street
http://www.techdigest.tv/android.jpg

A Jember
A Dowry
A 7, Monkey Street
http://cloud.somedomain.com/jm/a3.mp3
```

I'm kinda new to java and android dev, thank you so much in advanced for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firstname, lastname, address and url in the PhoneBookAudio are clobbering the details from the last PhoneBookEntry.

Either keep track of which state you're in, so make a note when you enter  that you care about what's happening now and clear the note when you leave , or add a "this.mParsedDataSetList = null" at the end of your endElement handler for a PhoneBookEntry.

Answer (score 0):

open the xml as InputStream (called "is" in the code below
then

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        /*

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
              baf.append((byte)current);
         }
        String ret = new String(baf.toByteArray(),GlobalVars.webencoding);
       */ 
        doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        String desc = "";

        if(doc.getElementsByTagName("description").getLength()>0){
            //do something like that
            int len = doc.getElementsByTagName("description").getLength();
            desc = doc.getElementsByTagName("description").item(len-1).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but do you know how to do it using sax parser?